# Install Visual studio 2015 in different drive

Tags: memory, visual-studio-2015, installation, drive

I have no space in my C drive. I want to install VIsual studio 2015 in D drive. But when i click exe file and run it shows the C drive path only..
How can i install in C drive ? 
Can anyone help me to done this?
Thank you..[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because once a set of shared components is installed, we install all the other components to the same directory structure. The workaround is to find the products that also installed these shared components and remove them, follow the steps as below extract from: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/14/how-to-install-visual-studio-to-another-directory-when-a-pre-release-is-installed/

1. Download and install http://psmsi.codeplex.com. These are general-purpose PowerShell cmdlets I created for all sorts of development and troubleshooting operations for Windows Installer-based installs. You do not need to elevate to install them, though if you pre-elevate you can install them per-machine (by default they are per-user).
2. Open an elevated PowerShell command prompt and run the following to discover which products have installed the key shared component: 
   get-msicomponentinfo '{777CBCAC-12AB-4A57-A753-4A7D23B484D3}' | get-msiproductinfo
3. If you’re fine with uninstalling all the listed products (especially given that you’re probably going to install RTM next), run the following: 
   get-msicomponentinfo '{777CBCAC-12AB-4A57-A753-4A7D23B484D3}' | get-msiproductinfo | uninstall-msiproduct -properties IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL