# How to install Visual Studio 2015 in external hard drive

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I need to install VS15 inside an external hard drive due to c drive memory ran out. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178274/install-visual-studio-2015-in-different-drive), is actually same problem but the answer provided (create mklink) I not really understand how to work in the correct steps. Does anyone can provide me the steps to install? I tried to install but

1) I able to ran after I install but I need the cross platform Xamarin, so when I wanna modify the updates, it say required memory spaces in both drivers (C: & D:), which is not enough spaces.

2) Is that possible to install the whole VS15 inside the external hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Your second question is a duplicate question for: [How to install Visual Studio 2015 on a different drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029751/how-to-install-visual-studio-2015-on-a-different-drive).

As for your first question I think you mean to ask whether dependancies for Xamarin (Android SDK, Emulators) can be installed on a external drive - I suppose this is possible. You'd have to install all dependancies (Android NDK/SDK etc.) to your external drive and then configure Visual Studio to use those folders (Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android settings).

Keep in mind this is not ideal, due to the large number of I/O operations that are performed during building things like Android apps, not even taking an emulator into consideration.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, for Q1, I mean that Control Panel > VS15 (change) > modify, I need to add on the cross platform mobile development (xamarin), but then it require 17gb in both drives, I have no idea how to deal with it. There is no any updates/install path I could change in the setup wizard.